# What is the NavigationLink symbol?

Tags: swift, symbols, swiftui-navigationlink

What is the symbol in the navigation link that looks like this: ">"

I'm trying to get it to use in my project but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use it in SwiftUI like…

```
Image(systemName: “chevron.right”)
```

If you download the app SF Symbols you can browse all the images that you can access using `systemName` like this.

https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/

Comment: I do have the app and tried this, and it's similar but not the exact same. The proportions are off. Is there any way to get the exact symbol? I could also screenshot it, and use an image, but there has to be another way, I'd hope.

Comment: Ah, I see. Hmm… I’ll have a look.

Comment: There is also a chevron.compact.right with a bit of a different shape. Is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: Still a little off. Anything else up your sleeve?

Comment: I used screenshots and .resizable() along with a set frame if you want to update your answer. Lmk if you find anything new. Thanks.

Comment: I found that you should have a better result if you play with the following code:
Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .font(.system(size: UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: .medium))
                    .opacity(0.35)